# background linear gradient position animation doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, gradient

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6NAHu/

As you can see the animation works in Chrome, but not in Firefox. The idea is to make a repeating animation by re-positioning the background.

The animation is called bg:

```
animation: bg 15s infinite linear;
```

Comment: Two notes. First, it should be "@keyframes bg..." not "@-keyframes bg..." Second, I appears to be an issue with background-position with %; it works with PX values. http://jsfiddle.net/6NAHu/1/

Comment: @-keyframes is fine. I found the problem. I should have used background-position: 0 100%; not background-position: 100% 0;. You see it right there, don't you?